# How does the extra rope length of this link/tangle scale with the inner triangle size?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, knot-theory, knot-link

The symmetric chiral link made of three long intertwined/linked/tangled flexible ropes of radius 1 shown in the figure, whose 6 ends all lie in a plane at spatial infinity and which are pulled outwards, requires some extra rope length compared to three ropes that are not intertwined/linked/tangled.

[image: symmetric chiral link made of three long intertwined/linked/tangled flexible ropes of radius 1]

The extra rope length is zero for an infinite size of the inner triangle.
The extra rope length increases when the inner triangle gets smaller.

How exactly does the extra rope length depend on the size of the inner triangle?

Clarification: the rope is assumed to always have a circular cross section, even if bent, and the rope length is defined as the length of the centerline of all circles. (This is common in knot theory.)
((The size of the inner triangle is not a uniquely defined quantity, especially if the ropes are not straight. Any definition is ok.))

Comment: I don't get it - isn't this simply $3(\sqrt{L^2 +4} -L)$ if we denote the triangle side length by $L$?

Comment: I think you will have to define the very notion of the "extra rope length", because the ropes will be of some non-cylindrical form, which is probably very complicated and depending on mechanical properties of the material of the rope.

Comment: Yes, the form is non-cylindrical. No, it does not depend on the material if the rope is always of circular cross section. Yes the from is complicated, because the radius is not neglegible compared to L.

Comment: The ropes are bent, and that is the hard part of the problem. The formula by Michael is an approximation that neglects the bends. It is not even clear whether, seen from above, the solution looks like three straight lines.

Comment: I get it even less than before. If you want to get into that much detail (more detail than the approximation I gave), then you have to specify the problem more. Apparently, the rope material is highly anisotropic (since it can go around a corner without losing circular cross section). Is it even describable by an elasticity tensor, or is it nonlinear? How strongly are we pulling on it? I agree with Iosif that, at this level of detail, more information on the mechanical properties is needed. You speak of solution. Solution to what? What is the dynamical equation governing the rope?

Comment: How is rope length even defined in bends of nonnegligible thickness? Inner curve, outer curve, line formed of the circular centers, something else?

Comment: @JukkaKohonen It is defined as the length of the line formed by the circular centers.

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt The idea is that the rope has a perfectly circular cross-section everywhere, even if bent. So, it is an "ideal" rope, no a real one. This assumption is common in knot theory.

Comment: I guess the shape you intend could described thus: The "midline" of a rope is an arbitrary curve with minimum radius of curvature being $1$, and length is measured along this midline. The rope itself is then the set of all points within distance $1$ of any point on the midline. In effect, ropes are then non-material circular "tubes".

Comment: Yes, indeed, this is what was intended.

Comment: Also, an alternative characterization would be that the three ropes are just the zero-thickness midline curves, with the requirement that the shortest distance between two ropes is at least $2$ (twice the rope radius).

Comment: Yes, indeed, that is also possible.

Comment: I think the question is now quite clear enough. (But still getting close votes for lack of clarity.)

Comment: I thought the OP wants the shortest-length solution.

Comment: Yes, that is the aim of the question.

Comment: I still don't get it. If we're minimizing the rope length (as now defined) without any constraint on the triangle size (even if we were to define it somehow), then there is no dependence on the size of the triangle - it is not a parameter we can tune, but something we determine as part of the optimization. In fact, the solution would be that the triangle becomes infinitely large. So, to define a nontrivial problem, a further constraint must be formulated.

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt : I think the problem can now be interpreted as follows: Suppose that the 6 ends of the ropes are at 6 points very far from the origin such that, if the ropes were straight lines, the triangle would be of the prescribed size. Now, given these endpoints of the three ropes, minimize (say) the total length of the midlines of the three ropes under the restriction that the shortest distance between any two midlines of the three ropes be at least $2$. Then let all the endpoints of the ropes go to infinity, say in a symmetric fashion. The question then would be ...

Comment: Allowing for nonstraight ropes (even looked from above), the triangle size condition could be interpreted as a condition that the midlines of the ropes, projected to the plane, pass through the vertices of the given triangle. Otherwise they are free to zigzag.